# "There is/are one teacher, one student and two players in the boat."

Tags: grammatical-number

If the subject is plural we use 'are', and if it is singular we use 'is'.

There is a pen on the table.

There are two pens on the table.

What about when there are multiple parts? As in: one teacher, one student and two players.

> A. There is one teacher, one student and two players in the boat.
>
> B. There are one teacher, one student and two players in the boat.

A or B?

Answer (score 1):

When there is a list of things, follow this rule:

> If the first noun listed is singular, use "There is".

> If the first noun listed is plural, use "There are".

Therefore, sentence (A) is ok.

> *"There is one teacher, one student and two players in the boat."*